# Uncaught ReferenceError : I am trying to use a button with OncLick method in JavaScript but keep getting error ,

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

I am trying to get a message when the button is clicked but I keep getting errors in my console and the button is not working. It's my first week in learning js.

The error I am getting in console is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: purchase is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (shoe.html:10:32)

```
let showMessage = document.getElementById("error=el");
let message = " sorry some error!"
function purchase(){
  //console.log('clicked');
  showMessage.textContent = message;
}
purchase();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="purchase()">Purchase</button>  
  <p Id="error-el"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the JS file loaded?

Comment: Your id is error-el and not error=el

Comment: I have linked it in html , I have changed to error-el but still same issue is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

There are some small mistakes in the code that I fixed,

- The id attribute should be in lower case
- In getting element by Id function you're looking for `error=el` instead of `error-el`. The problem here was the `=` instead of `-`

```js
let showMessage = document.getElementById("error-el");
let message = " sorry some error!"
function purchase(){
  showMessage.textContent = message;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="purchase()">Purchase</button>  
  <p id="error-el"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help but in my browser it still not working. it =s keep giving me error shoe.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: purchase is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (shoe.html:10:32)
onclick @ shoe.html:10

Comment: Did you tried to run the code snippet I added here

Answer (score 0):

To use JavaScript in your HTML, you should load the script from another file using a `<src>` tag or write it directly into the .html file with a `<script>` tag.